# Jests test broke when I added module.exports = MyClass

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, node-modules, ts-jest

I've been struggling with creating a working NPM package using TypeScript, and testing with Jest and the `ts-jest` package.  The code is now solid and all the unit tests passed until I made this project into a proper module/package to be consumed in a Node app or on a webapp.

### My Code

I have a class that contains all my code, in `./src/index.ts`

```ts
export class MyClass {
  static parse(){
    return "foo"
  }
}

module.exports = MyClass;
```

I have a simple tests file `./src/index.tests.ts`

```ts
import { MyClass } from "./index";

it('should...'){
  expect(MyClass.parse()).toEqual("foo");
}
```

### My Configuration

Here is my `./tsconfig.ts` file

```json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "allowUnusedLabels": false,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "declaration": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "esModuleInterop":true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "types": ["node"],
    "useDefineForClassFields": false,
    "lib": ["ES2022", "dom"]
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["./dist/**/*", "./src/**/*.test.ts"]
}
```

and then I have a `./tsconfig.test.ts` file which extends the main one

```json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["jest", "node"],
    "outDir": "./out-test",
  },
  "include": ["./**/*.test.ts", "./**/*.d.ts"],
  "exclude": ["./dist/**/*", "./out-test/**/*"]
}
```

and finally, I have a `./jest.config.ts` file:

```ts
import type { Config } from "@jest/types";

// Sync object
const config: Config.InitialOptions = {
  verbose: true,
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.ts$": "ts-jest",
  },
};

export default config;
```

### My Problem

When I run `tsc --project tsconfig.json` it builds fine, files go into `/dist` as expected.

When I run `tsc --project tsconfig.test.json` that also builds fine.

However, when I run `jest` to run the tests I get this error:

```txt
 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'parse')

      219 |
      220 |   it("should...", () => {
    > 221 |     expect(MyClass.parse(
          |                    ^
```

If I change my `./src/index.ts` file to use `export default MyClass;` instead, the above error goes away but I get this instead

```txt
 src/index.test.ts:220:5 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'expect'.

    220     expect(MyClass.parse(
            ~~~~~~
```

And similar errors for `it()` and `describe()` as well.

Is there something special I have to do to get this working again now that I'm using a module?

Comment: Let's try to add `"rootDir": "./",` to your jest config file.

Comment: See my update as an answer below.  I'm like 95% of the way there I think.  Would doing this be an improvement over what I've done in my answer?

Comment: `export class MyClass { ... }; module.exports = MyClass;` makes no sense whatsoever. It certainly will _not_ provide an export named `MyClass`.

Comment: Thanks, yes I've found that out.  Now I am just using `export class MyClass` and that is working.  I was flailing around to try anything that works. I've got it figure out now.

Answer (score 1):

The big thing I found was that my Jest configuration needed to be changed to point to my `tsconfig.test.json` file like this:

```ts
import type { Config } from "@jest/types";

// Sync object
const config: Config.InitialOptions = {
  verbose: true,
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.ts$": [
      "ts-jest",
      {
        tsconfig: "tsconfig.test.json",
      },
    ],
  },
  preset: "ts-jest",
};

export default config;
```

I had to run `npm i --save-dev @types/node`

I also had to add `"node"` to my list of types in my `tsconfig.tests.json` file, and I also modified the `include` pattern to only look inside the `./src/` folder, like this:

```json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["jest", "node"],
    "outDir": "./out-test/",
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*.ts", "./src/**/*.d.ts"],
  "exclude": ["./dist/**/*", "./out-test/**/*"]
}
```

in my main class I had to `export` it as follows instead:

```
export class myClass {
  static parse(){
    return "foo";
  }
}
```

Doing all these things allows for both TS projects to build, and the tests to run successfully. I am also able to include this package on my Angular/TypeScript web app and it works exactly as it should.